# connecting web form to servlet

Tags: servlets

As of now I get the error message class not fount yadiyadiyada, seen in the following image.
I am in the web.xml of my server and at the bottom is the mapping. In the solution explorer, the servlet is login.java. (I am assuming the url pattern and servlet name are correct...they did not give an error)

I now know the correct path to my servlet. Thank you, but it was apparently not the issue. Any body know what could cause this error?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating my own web.xml file in my projects WEB-INF folder and then making the form action "login", the url-pattern "login" and the servlet name "login".

edit
I also correctly set the path to servlets.java

Comment: what is your <servlet-class>? It should be servlets.login based on the screenshot of your project explorer.

Comment: It is servlets.login, the reason I initially asked what the path was is it did not work....So I was confused. I tried many many things until I got fed up and posted here. I honestly have no Idea why it did not work. I did some more research and realized I could crete my own web.xml (did not know that) and tried again. Then I got a new error saying the ressource /login was not found...I don't know why it suddently said that, so I switched everything else to login and it worked. I think / makes it think its a folder or something, who knows.

Comment: /login is url pattern. Basically, if your request url is http://host:port/<webapp_context>/login/.., the servlet container will invoke the login servlet. It has nothing to do with folder. Anyway, glad you make it work, although I still think your original ClassNotFoundException is caused by the wrong class name.

Comment: I tried it with servlets.login  like you said and it did not work. At least then I knew to look somewhere else. Your help was helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not servlet path. The error is `ClassNotFoundException`. In the `<servlet-class>` tag, you put `RoboMonkey.JavaResources.src.servlets.login`. That's not the right full class name of your servlet. Please put `servlets.login` instead.

Comment: I did that and I get the exact same error. What else could cause that kinda of problem?